# epoll and timeouts

Tags: c, events, epoll

I'm using epoll to manage about 20 to 30 sockets. I figure out that epoll_wait can be used to wait for some data to arrive over one of the socket but I'm missing how do I implement timeouts on socket level. I can use timeout on epoll_wait but it not very useful in my case. For example, if I need to every close a socket where no activity is recorded for > 500 ms orr may be send some data to a socket every 200 ms no matter what. How can these socket level timeout be implemented using epoll? Any suggestion and idea would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Shivam Kalra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to write an event loop (if so have a look at [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) btw).  `epoll` will not help you there, you have to keep track of socket inactivity yourself (`clock_gettime()` or `gettimeofday()` for instance), then wake up several times a second and check everything you need.

Some pseudo code

```
while (1) {
    n = epoll_wait(..., 5);
    if (n > 0) {
        /* process activity */
    } else {
        /* process inactivity */
    }
}
```

This will wake you up 200 times a second if all sockets are inactive.

The inactivity check requires a list of the sockets to be examined along with timestamps of the last inactivity:

```
struct sockstamp_s {
    /* socket descriptor */
    int sockfd;
    /* last active */
    struct timeval tv;
};

/* check which socket has been inactive */
for (struct sockstamp_s *i = socklist; ...; i = next(i)) {
    if (diff(s->tv, now()) > 500) {
        /* socket s->sockfd was inactive for more than 500 ms */
        ...
    }
}
```

where `diff()` gives you the difference of 2 `struct timeval`s and `now()` gives you the current timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I was wondering, if I could use inactivity check with epoll wait for very small time may be about 10 ms? Do I get any performance improvement over select + inactivity chec?

Comment: Depends, the more often you wake up the more CPU you will consume.  Also, you need a 1000 HZ kernel to wake up every millisecond.  Like I said, I highly suggest a ready event-loop (like libev, or libevent) which are optimised to these situations (at the price of a dependency).

Answer (score 12):

Try pairing each socket with a timer fd object ([`timerfd_create`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timerfd_create)). For each socket in your application, create a timer that's initially set to expire after 500ms, and *add the timer to the epoll object* (same as with a socket—via `epoll_ctl` and `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`). Then, whenever data arrives on a socket, reset that socket's associated timer back to a 500ms timeout.

If a timer expires (because a socket has been inactive for 500ms) then the timer will become "read ready" in the epoll object and cause any thread waiting on `epoll_wait` to wake up. That thread may then handle the timeout for the timer's associated socket.